# Show sharepoint list in a datagridview using c #

Tags: sharepoint-online, asp.net

I would like to know how to show a list of sharepoint in a page of asp.net c # by means of a datagridview and be able to modify it by adding a record to the list by means of a button.

Beforehand thank you very much!!

---

I thank you for your prompt reply Mohamed El-Qassas but I already did this, what I want now is to bring a list created in online sharepoint to a datagrid of a page of asp.net bone to make a maintenance of records what I add, modify or delete in that datagrid by means of buttons do it also in the online sharepoint

I want something like that for example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use the **Client Side Object Model** to interact with SharePoint Online from your ASP.Net App.

**First,** you should add the below references to your solution

- Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll
- Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll

---

**Add List Item**

```
string WebUrl = "https://You.sharepoint.com/sites/ABC/";
string login = "**********";
string password = "**********";
var securePassword = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in password)
    {securePassword.AppendChar(c);}
var onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securePassword);
#endregion

#region Insert the data
using (ClientContext CContext = new ClientContext(WebUrl))
{
CContext.Credentials = onlineCredentials;
List announcementsList = CContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Supply GateWay");
ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem newItem = announcementsList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
newItem["Title"] = C_Name.Value;
newItem["Address"] = C_Address.Value;
newItem.Update();
CContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

**A lot of code samples at**

- [Complete basic operations using SharePoint client library code](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code)
- [How to Get All List Items Of A List Using REST API In SharePoint Online And Office 365](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-get-all-list-items-of-a-list-using-rest-api-in-sharepoint-online-and-offi/)
- [How to retrieve list elements from a SharePoint Online list programmatically](http://geekswithblogs.net/ThorvaldBoe/archive/2015/07/07/how-to-retrieve-list-elements-from-a-sharepoint-online-list.aspx)
- [Client Object Model: Introduction](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/399156/SharePoint-Client-Object-Model-Introduction)
- [Add List Item in SharePoint Online using ASP.net and C#](http://www.daoudisamir.com/add-list-item-in-sharepoint-online-using-asp-net-and-c/)

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.mukeshkumar.net/articles/aspnet/crud-operation-in-asp-net-gridview-using-single-stored-procedure) is a good template with CRUD function in asp.net gridview by `asp:TemplateField` with control events(OnRowDeleting/OnRowEditing/OnRowUpdating etc.).

You could achieve insert function in footer template also, [follow this official demo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/enhancing-the-gridview/inserting-a-new-record-from-the-gridview-s-footer-cs).

Hope this would help you.